# Getting error "specified network name is no longer available" as soon as I try to open file

Tags: vba, excel, filesystemobject

In VBA for excel I'm using the `FileSystemObject` to loop through the files in a folder, then when I find an excel file I'm trying to open it and update any hyperlinks in the file.

Whenever I try to open a file in excel, I receive the error message `Run-time error '2147024832 (80070040)':  Automation error   The specified network name is no longer available.`  The attempt to open the file fails, and if I step back through the code after this event, I no longer seem to be able to "see" the files in the folder object.

For example, if there are 6 files in a folder, and the last one is an excel file, the `ModifyFiles` function will loop through the first 5 files, see that they aren't excel files, and move to the next.  On the last it will properly recognize the excel file and call the `IsWorkBookOpen` function,if it is not open, it succeeds in checking and then it proceeds to call the `UpdateLinks` procedure. When it hits the line to open the file, it takes a second like it's trying access the file, then I get the aforementioned error message and it fails to execute the open command.  After that, if I go back to the calling procedure and try to loop through the files again, it will give me the same error message on the `For each fileX in foldX` line.

It's as if trying to open the file is breaking my connection to the server.

Any suggestions?

My code (server names and shares have been changed, but I checked them for accuracy and they are good):

```
Option Explicit
Dim strLISTMOD()            As String
Dim strLISTFAIL()           As String

Sub Main()
    Dim blnE    As Boolean
    Dim blnA    As Boolean
    Dim blnS    As Boolean

        With Application
            blnE = .EnableEvents
            blnA = .DisplayAlerts
            blnS = .ScreenUpdating
            .EnableEvents = False
            .DisplayAlerts = False
            .ScreenUpdating = False
        End With

    ReDim strLISTMOD(0 To 0)
    ReDim strLISTFAIL(0 To 0)
    FileDigger "\\myserver\myshare\"

        With Application
            .EnableEvents = blnE
            .DisplayAlerts = blnA
            .ScreenUpdating = blnS
        End With
End Sub

Private Function IsWorkBookOpen(ByRef strFILENAME As String)
    Dim lngX                As Long
    Dim lngErr              As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    lngX = FreeFile()
    Open strFILENAME For Input Lock Read As #lngX
    Close lngX
    lngErr = Err
    On Error GoTo 0

        Select Case lngErr
            Case 0:    IsWorkBookOpen = False
            Case 70:   IsWorkBookOpen = True
            Case Else: Error lngErr
        End Select
End Function

Private Function FileDigger(strDIRECTORY As String) As String

    Dim oFsoX               As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim foldX               As Scripting.Folder
    Dim foldY               As Scripting.Folder
    Dim lngErr              As Long

    Set oFsoX = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

    On Error Resume Next
    Set foldX = oFsoX.GetFolder(strDIRECTORY)
    lngErr = Err
    On Error GoTo 0

        If Not foldX Is Nothing Then
            ModifyFiles foldX
                For Each foldY In foldX.SubFolders
                    FileDigger = FileDigger(foldY.Path)
                Next
        End If

End Function

Private Sub ModifyFiles(ByRef foldDIR As Scripting.Folder)
    Dim fileX               As Scripting.File

        For Each fileX In foldDIR.Files
            If fileX.Name Like "*.xls*" Then
                    If Not IsWorkBookOpen(fileX.Path) Then
                        UpdateLinks fileX.Path
                        AddToList fileX.Name, True
                    Else
                        AddToList fileX.Name, False
                    End If
            End If
        Next
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateLinks(strPATH As String)
    Dim lnkX    As Excel.Hyperlink
    Dim wshX    As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim wbkX    As Excel.Workbook

    Set wbkX = Application.Workbooks.Open(strPATH, True, False, , , , True)
    For Each wshX In wbkX.Worksheets
       For Each lnkX In wshX.Hyperlinks
            lnkX.Address = Replace(lnkX.Address, "\\oldserver\oldshare\", "\\newserver\newshare\")
        Next lnkX
    Next
    wbkX.Close True

End Sub

Private Sub AddToList(ByRef strFILENAME As String, ByRef blnMODIFIED As Boolean)
    Dim strLIST()   As String

        If blnMODIFIED Then strLIST = strLISTMOD Else strLIST = strLISTFAIL

    If Len(strLIST(0)) > 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve strLIST(0 To UBound(strLIST) + 1)
        strLIST(UBound(strLIST)) = strFILENAME
    Else
        strLIST(0) = strFILENAME
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I would first collect all of your file names, and *then* loop through them to make the required changes - modifying files while at the same time looping over them can cause strange results.

Comment: @TimWilliams - thanks, I will try that and report back

Comment: @TimWilliams - I tried changing the loop to add the files to an array and then process from the array, but I'm getting the same error still.  I also noticed if I step all the way back to the main procedure after the error starts, when I get to the `FileDigger` procedure and it tries to get the first folder, I get an error message "permission denied" - so really not sure what's going on with that.

Comment: I would remove that "on error resume next" unless you expect there are folders you won't have access to: otherwise you're going to miss problems.  Or at least print a debug message whenever you get an error.

Comment: @TimWilliams - I'm using the lngErr variable to capture any errors at that point. I hadn't added any error reporting yet, but I'm just stepping through line by line at this point and I'm able to watch it in the locals window. There are folders my account might not have access to, so that is why I have that block.

Comment: Okay, so after changing opening the files from an array:  When I get to the line that calls the open command it executes and I see a flash of a workbook being added to the list of projects in the VBA project window - but it immediately closes (is removed from the projects tree) and the code actually steps back to the previous line (which is in the calling procedure).  If I continue to step through, when it gets to that line again and tries to execute it that's when I get the `network name is no longer available` error message.

Comment: I just tested typing the `application.workbooks.open` call in the immediate window with the filename that I keep failing on.  When the macro is not running, I am able to open the file without issue using this method.  So I think it has to do with the file system object somehow.  I might try destroying this object before I attempt to open and modify files.  Will report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I have this solved.  Thanks to @TimWilliams - your original comment really was the solution.  I'm not 100% sure on the root cause of the problem - which if anyone knows and cares to explain I'm extremely curious to learn - but the problem seems to be that I was trying to access the file before I was done accessing the folder with the `FileSystemObject` object.  I don't know if the FSO object reserves each folder and it's children or what, but I found if I destroy the FSO object then I could access the files.  What I ended up doing was modifying the `FileDigger` function so that I am constructing the entire list of all the files to modify from the root directory and all subfolders BEFORE I try to open any file in excel.  I used a Boolean flag to identify the base case of the recursive `FileDigger` procedure and then I just destroy the FSO object before calling the `ModifyFiles` procedure.

This seems to work in testing.  I'll have to wait until the workday is over to run it on the entire network share as I don't want to create that much traffic while people are accessing files on that share.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that when you open a file in Excel it will create a file named "~name of file here.xlsx" in the same folder - that could easily confuse your process if it's not immediately cleaned up on closing the file.